# WebSocket and game positionning frequency and event granularity

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I m developping with Node.js and some HTML5 stuff. I want to develop a little game where people can join a map, and move on it, something really simple.

My questions are :

- Is node.js a good alternative to make online games, even if there s no threads ?
- When should I send a user position ? I think it's bad to send the position everytime a player is moving, it may be hard for the server to manage every request and I ll get to many latency, am I wrong ?

I hope you can help me

Thanks for all,

Have nice day

EDIT : Admiting that my game is 50 maps (50 rooms) and has 50 players / rooms (2500 players). Should I use high granularity events like "toTop" to move to the top ? Or an event like "move" is okay, to manage every deplacements ?

Comment: You don't need threads. Node.js does have a very lightweight concurrency primitive - its event loop.

Comment: The server doesn't need to manage single requests when there are open websocket connections to all online players. You can push immediately.

Comment: I know that I can push to every player on an event. But imagine, if I send my position to every online players (on keyDown for example), there will be many push. What happens if 500 players send there position at the same time for 10 seconds of keyDown ?

Comment: I think 500 players should be easily manageable by a Nodejs server via websockets. Of course you will need to filter events a little, you don't need to broadcast every single key event from every player to every player.

Comment: Okay, so I should manage by different event, corresponding to the action. Should I decompose with high granularity ? Like event "topTop" when user decide to move to the top ? or "move" is okay ? And I guess you're thinking of using rooms corresponding to my maps , Am I write ?

Comment: Rooms? Definitely. But for any suggestions on the event types, I would need to know more about your game. You might want to post a new question for that.

Comment: I ve editted my post to not create another one. Thanks for your help.